# How to get extra data into a python package?

Tags: python, distutils

I have a python package that I'm writing. The directory structure resembles this:

```
root
  |- requirements.txt
  |- MANIFEST.in
  |- setup.py
  |- config.cfg
  |- src
       |- foo
            |- __init__.py
            |- foo.py
            |- extra_files
                 |- bar.txt
                 |- baz.txt
```

The `setup.py` looks like this:

```
import setuptools
import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
parser.read('config.cfg')

setuptools.setup(name=parser.get('release', 'name'),
    version=parser.get('release', 'version'),
    package_dir={'foo': 'src/foo'},
    packages=['foo'],
    provides=['foo'],
    package_data={'foo': ['extra_files']},
    install_requires=open('requirements.txt').readlines()
    )
```

And `MANIFEST.in` looks like this:

```
include config.cfg
include requirements.txt
recursive-include src/foo/extra_files *
```

Now, when I create the package tarball with `python setup.py sdist`, all of the files under `extra_files` get added to the tarball that's generated. However, when I run `pip install` on another machine, the `extra_files` are nowhere to be found; all I have is `foo.py`. How can I get these files to be propagated?